# RaspberryPi with 7inch HDMI Screen not working

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, screen

I bought a Raspberry Pi model B 3. Also I bought a 7 inch HDMI touch screen display for it.

> If I connect the 7" HDMI touch screen's HDMI cable to my mac, the
>   screen works fine.
>
> If I connect the Raspberry pi with an HDMI monitor, it displays
>   perfectly.

**When I connect the HDMI screen with Raspberry pi. It does not show anything on screen. It just shows a white ribbon on the screen.**

*My Raspberry pi uses, Raspbian Jessie OS.*

Above shows I need to change some configuration in Raspberry Pi for displaying in small screen. Kindly help me for the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue with the hdmi display. I got a manuel for this device and there I found the correct configuration.

Open the `/boot/config.txt` file and change/add the following lines:

```
max_usb_current=1
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=1
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt 1024 600 60 6 0 0 0
```

If you had another resolution than 1024x600, please change it in hdmi_cvt.

Answer (score 0):

You should edit your /conf.txt file, for example, I'm using a Raspberry Pi with a 5" HDMI screen and it works perfectly, all you have to do is go to the file and config the (hdmi_mode) in the HDMI section. In my case was `hdmi_mode = 14`. If you are looking the line in this way: `#hdmi_mode = 1` make sure you remove the "#" add your screen resolution number and then reboot the Raspberry.